# Boostrap 4 Colum Display

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use this code 
https://codepen.io/Navedkhan012/pen/owdxWg
for display images in my codeigniter website with bootstrap 4. You can see all images in above demo is getting displayed horizontally but in Mine above codes getting displayed vertically like below image.
[image]

My Modal code is like below in which I am trying to use it.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" media="screen">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>




<!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body" sytle ="background-color:black;">



     <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='list-group gallery'>
            <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
                <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="http://placehold.it/300x320.png">
                    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/320x320" />
                    <div class='text-right'>
                        <small class='text-muted'>Image Title</small>
                    </div> <!-- text-right / end -->
                </a>
            </div> <!-- col-6 / end -->
            <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
                <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="http://placehold.it/300x320.png">
                    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/320x320" />
                    <div class='text-right'>
                        <small class='text-muted'>Image Title</small>
                    </div> <!-- text-right / end -->
                </a>
            </div> <!-- col-6 / end -->
            <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
                <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="http://placehold.it/300x320.png">
                    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/320x320" />
                    <div class='text-right'>
                        <small class='text-muted'>Image Title</small>
                    </div> <!-- text-right / end -->
                </a>
            </div> <!-- col-6 / end -->
            <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
                <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="http://placehold.it/300x320.png">
                    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/320x320" />
                    <div class='text-right'>
                        <small class='text-muted'>Image Title</small>
                    </div> <!-- text-right / end -->
                </a>
            </div> <!-- col-6 / end -->
            <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
                <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="http://placehold.it/300x320.png">
                    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/320x320" />
                    <div class='text-right'>
                        <small class='text-muted'>Image Title</small>
                    </div> <!-- text-right / end -->
                </a>
            </div> <!-- col-6 / end -->
            <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
                <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="http://placehold.it/300x320.png">
                    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/320x320" />
                    <div class='text-right'>
                        <small class='text-muted'>Image Title</small>
                    </div> <!-- text-right / end -->
                </a>
            </div> <!-- col-6 / end -->
        </div> <!-- list-group / end -->
    </div> <!-- row / end -->
</div> <!-- container / end -->








        </div>
        <!-- Modal body End-->
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>














<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //FANCYBOX
    //https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        openEffect: "none",
        closeEffect: "none"
    });
});


</script>
```

Let me know if someone can correct me. Thanks!

Comment: its only html you showed above, what about css and the js? have you done that as well?

Comment: @Kevin I have used same css and js codes as well in codepen. Thanks!

Comment: @Kevin I have added js and css codes as well with edit question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is working as expected! May  be problem is the way it is displayed in modal dialog.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //FANCYBOX
  //https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    openEffect: "none",
    closeEffect: "none"
  });
});
```

```css
.gallery {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" media="screen">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='list-group gallery'>
      <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
        <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="http://placehold.it/300x320.png">
          <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/320x320" />
          <div class='text-right'>
            <small class='text-muted'>Image Title</small>
          </div>
          <!-- text-right / end -->
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- col-6 / end -->
      <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
        <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="http://placehold.it/300x320.png">
          <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/320x320" />
          <div class='text-right'>
            <small class='text-muted'>Image Title</small>
          </div>
          <!-- text-right / end -->
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- col-6 / end -->
      <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
        <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="http://placehold.it/300x320.png">
          <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/320x320" />
          <div class='text-right'>
            <small class='text-muted'>Image Title</small>
          </div>
          <!-- text-right / end -->
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- col-6 / end -->
      <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
        <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="http://placehold.it/300x320.png">
          <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/320x320" />
          <div class='text-right'>
            <small class='text-muted'>Image Title</small>
          </div>
          <!-- text-right / end -->
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- col-6 / end -->
      <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
        <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="http://placehold.it/300x320.png">
          <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/320x320" />
          <div class='text-right'>
            <small class='text-muted'>Image Title</small>
          </div>
          <!-- text-right / end -->
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- col-6 / end -->
      <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
        <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="http://placehold.it/300x320.png">
          <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/320x320" />
          <div class='text-right'>
            <small class='text-muted'>Image Title</small>
          </div>
          <!-- text-right / end -->
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- col-6 / end -->
    </div>
    <!-- list-group / end -->
  </div>
  <!-- row / end -->
</div>
<!-- container / end -->
```